# Sending a Gif with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()

freedom_gif = ['https://media.tenor.com/m0ixMJiY09cAAAAC/aot-attack-on-titan.gif']
freedom_names = ['freedom','yikes']

@bot.command()
async def freedom(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=(discord.Embed.Colour.random()),
        description =f"{ctx.author.mention} {(random.choice(freedom_names))}"
     )
     embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(freedom_gif)))
     await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Every time I try and use the !freedom Command it does not sent the gif when I use the command. What is happening? The bot is online and other events work

Answer (score 0):

Your bot doesn't have any intents enabled.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

You also don't need to create a `discord.Client` as you already have a `commands.Bot` (the latter inherits from the former).

You will also need to go the Discord Developer portal and enabled the "message content" intent for your application's bot as well otherwise it won't work.

- [primer on intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)
- [discord.py quickstart with intents enabled](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Comment: I have enabled it in the Discord portal but in python, I get this error                     
AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you on?

Comment: I am use whatever is on replit

Comment: @JacobZabel Replit is just an IDE. You have to install discord.py separately. I believe you can check this with pip list.